# How to add asterisk in a label and add different css to it in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add an asterisk on my label, and want to change the colour of the asterisk to red without changing the colour of the rest of the label. The CSS for the label is in Textfield itself which is a component.
Following is the code:

```
<TextField className="sign-up-input-field"
                    value={loginId}
                    placeholder="Enter Login ID"
                    label="Login ID *"
                    handleChange={
                        (e) => {
                            if (e.target.value) 
                                setShowEmptyFieldError(false)
                            
                            setIsLoginPage(true);
                            setLoginId(e.target.value)
                        }
                    }
                    id="prospect-sign-in-login-id-input"
                    type="number"
                    
                    labelStyles={
                        {
                            fontFamily: "Roboto",
                            fontStyle: "normal",
                            display: "block",
                            fontWeight: "400",
                            fontSize: "16px",
                            lineHeight: "24px",
                            letterSpacing: "0.03em",
                            color: "#312126"
                            

                        }
                    }/>
```

How can I add css to the asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS class and pseudo-element for that :

```
.myLabel {
    /* color for the label*/
}
.myLabel::after {
    content: "*";
    /* color and properties of the asterix
}
```